# How to arrange ggplot2 plots making their plot area widths equal?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

Take this nice plot below: it arranges plots but the width of each plot area is different because of the left-side `axis.text` (1...3 or 50...70).

Is it possible to make the areas equal, so we could compare the upper and lower plots with each other?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by equal areas? Do you want to force the y axis to be 1-70 for both the plots? Isn't that the plot height and not the width?

Comment: @TylerRinker Absolutely agree. Sorry, didn't find through search. Thanks. Voted for close.